# How can I get the id of a draggable table row when using the jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I need to get the `id` from a table row that is "draggable". Everything works fine except for "ID_1". I can't seem to get this value. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="droppable" id="value_2">
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>

<table>
    <tr class="draggable" id="value_1">
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ID_1
$(".draggable").draggable({cursor: 'move', 
    helper: function(event) {
        return $('<div class="drag_row"><table></table></div>')
        .find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end();
    },
    appendTo: 'body'
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui)
        {
            ID_1 = $(this).find("tr").attr('id');
        },
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
        var ID_2 = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'www.mydomain.com/'+ID_1+'/'+ID_2,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(){
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do you have a jsfiddle demonstrating this?

Comment: I added the basic form of the HTML. There are several rows in both tables, and each row has its own ``id`` (of course).

Answer (score 2):

Use `ui.draggable` to get the dragged element, So the code should be :

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
     over: function(event, ui) {
        ID_1 = ui.draggable.attr('id');
     },
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
       var ID_2 = ui.draggable.attr('id');
       // existing stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I think it is because of how I am wrapping the draggable ``tr`` inside a ``table`` tag when it is being dragged.

Comment: @ClaireEmery, the ui.draggable represents the whole dragged element, if you want to find the id of particular element in it that use **ui.draggable.find("selector").attr("id")**

Comment: You could try event.target.id; inseated

Answer (score 0):

You could use event.target.id instead

Here is a fiddle (from old project), display the console.log to see log about overed container : http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/QvRjL/97/

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
     over: function(event, ui) {
        ID_1 = event.target.id;
     },
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
       var ID_2 = event.target.id;
       // existing stuff
    }
});
```